# how to assign admin role for user who registers first in users sections using node js

Tags: node.js

**There should be two models Users and User_Roles.
First time when user registers, the User_Roles table should contain value as admin for that user and for rest of them
it should be different**

Comment: `newuser.isadmin = users.length === 0` If you need more https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask